Calcualting Medians in SQL
I am trying to figure out how to calculate MEDIAN in GROUPS within SQL (i.e. required to use NTILE() functions to indirectly calculate the median).
I read somewhere on the internet that some SQL servers do not support the MEDIAN function, whereas some of them do.
For example, I am doing something like:
select
 count(*) as total_count, 
median(height) as median_height, 
median(weight) as median_weight 
from football_players
group by country_of_origin;

This code ran correctly, but after having read that some SQL servers do not support the MEDIAN function, I am suspicious if I have done everything correctly.
I am using Netezza btw.
Is this correct?

SQL Server doesn not have MEDIAN function yet.
The closest function is the PERCENTILE function and get the 50th Percentile.
for example:
select 
  country_of_origin,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY height)
    OVER (PARTITION BY country_of_origin) AS MedianCont,
  PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY height)
    OVER (PARTITION BY country_of_origin) AS MedianDisc
from football_players;

PERCENTILE_CONT calculates based on continuous number as PERCENTILE_DISC on discrete.
if you'd like to do it manually however, it gets a little bit messy.
SELECT 
   (
    MAX(CASE WHEN rownum <= 0.50 * totalrow THEN height END) +
    MIN(CASE WHEN rownum >= 0.50 * totalrow THEN height END)
   ) / 2.0 AS percentile_50
FROM (
    SELECT 
       country_of_origin,
       height,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_of_origin) AS rownum,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country_of_origin) AS total
    FROM football_players n
) subquery;

